# Instance created inside of a Method

Tags: java, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have not been able to find any reliable literature on this but i'm curious as to where an object is stored if its created inside of a method ? on the stack or on the heap in java 8?

```
public class A {}
.
.
.
public class B { 
  public void test(){
   A m = new A();
  }
}
```

I know that normally only local primitives, reference variables and function calls are stored on the stack and that objects are stored in the heap

So I'm assuming that one of the following two scenarios is true either

- **Case 1 :** Objects instantiated in a method are as usual stored in the heap with a reference to that object in the stack then when the function finishes the object reference goes out of scope and the object in the heap is then available for garbage collection
- **Case 2 :** Objects instantiated in a method are stored in the stack then are available for garbage collection when function finishes

I strongly suspect its case 1, it wouldn't make sense to store an object in a stack, the only reason I have doubts is because ive come across some literature saying on the stack and others on the heap

Thanks for your feedback ahead of time

Comment: Object instances are *conceptually* stored in the heap. How the JVM implementation really works is completely up to the JVM itself. A JVM is free to store them on punchcards and reread them every time they're needed, as long as it looks from the Java code as if they're on the heap. In some cases, the current oracle JVM actually replaces you object allocation with a stack allocation of all its fields, but it first ensures that it only does that when your application cannot notice the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local reference variable is on the stack, and the object is in the heap.

Note that your question title,

> Instance declared inside of a Method

is misleading since objects/instances are declared ***nowhere*** -- only variables are, and the object created in a method can be placed on fields into a collection, or anywhere it's needed. And so there is no guarantee that the object *should* be GC'd when the method exits.

Comment: haha you're right I changed , thanks for the quick response I suspected case 1 was right I just wanted to make sure

Comment: Minor syntactic point: while objects aren't declared inside a method, classes can be: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

All the objects are stored in the heap ... the garbage collector runs whenever there's a lack of memory so it get rid of the objects that are not used anymore and there's no reference to them too.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption specified in Case 1 is correct. Here is a good source on memory allocation in java.

[Java Heap Space vs Stack – Memory Allocation in Java](https://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory)

Answer (score 0):

If they are not immediate "values" (not like an int property in a class object), only their reference values are stored in the stack. their actual values and structures are stored in the heap.

these are stored in the stack as they are;

```
int i=10;
float f=10.00;
bool b=true;
```

these will have only references on the stack, they will reside in the heap (any kind of class variable is part of the structure and be created on the heap altogether);

```
int[] ii={1,2,3};
double[] dd = new double[10];
String s="String!!";
Object o=new Object();
```

when passed to a method, Values are copied to a new stack variable (unless converted to a reference object). References are also passed to a copycat stack variable, but since they are references, both will redirect to the same object (unless copied to a whole new object manually).

---

**this part might not be of interest in the topic, you decide**

In the following code, number is created on the stack and copied to a new stack value for the method, hello created on the heap, passed by reference to s then two strings concatenated on another heap address and it now holds this new address (strings are immutable). The Point object is not immutable as strings, so it can be changed anywhere you referenced it as they are created on the heap to access freely.

```
class Point{ int x;int y;  Point(int x,int y){this.x=x;this.y=y;} }

public class TestClass{
     public static void main(String []args){
        int number=5;
        String hello="Hello";
        Point point = new Point(2,4);
        Print(number,hello,point);
        System.out.println(hello+" "+number+" "+point.x+" "+point.y);
     }
     public static void Print(int i,String s,Point p){
        i+=5;
        s+="World!";
        p.x+=2; p.y+=2;
        System.out.println(s+" "+i+" "+p.x+" "+p.y);
     }
}
```